# numpy covariance compared to excel covariance difference

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, covariance

I am calculating covariance of dataset using Numpy.Cov() function for sample dataset below and I am getting discrepancy compared to calculating covariance using Excel covariance function.

I am unable to find the root cause of discrepancy and hence any help will be appreciated

### Data

```
 CL1            CL2              CL3
11.61815873     27.01813137      25.284136
11.77125896     27.15483024     25.77108973
11.70410973     26.89751471     25.59316433
11.81557745     26.96184359     25.76172524
11.83437923     27.21915913     25.76172524
```

### Excel Covariance Values

```
    CL1             CL2             CL3
CL1 0.006270349     
CL2 0.004384429     0.014328536 
CL3 0.014014102     0.008418645     0.035098552
```

However when I run numpy_array.cov() function I get the following matrix

### Numpy Cov() function

```
        CL1         CL2         CL3
   CL1  0.007838    0.005481    0.017518
   CL2  0.005481    0.017911    0.010523
   CL3  0.017518    0.010523    0.043873
```

I will appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: It seems likely that Excel's covariance implementation computes the population covariance (N in the denominator) where Numpy computes sample covariance (N-1 in the denominator). I don't have direct evidence so can't write an answer though.

Comment: To get the same values as Excel using [`numpy.cov()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html), use the argument `ddof=0`.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. It explains the difference between biased and unbiased by use of degrees of freedom (ddof).